# Drush command to show site information configuration

Tags: drush

I would like to display all available information about a site using its alias name.

the closer thing I could find is drush status.

```
$ drush @loc.my-project-7-26-2-5-dev status
```

> PHP executable        :  xxxxxxxx
>   PHP configuration     :  xxxxxxxx
>   PHP OS                :  xxxxxxxx
>   Drush version         :  xxxxxxxx
>   Drush configuration   :  xxxxxxxx
>   Drush alias files     :  xxxxxxxx

I would like the site information, such as Drupal version, profile name, default theme, temporary directory path etc.. to be displayed instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running multisite then you can do

```
$ drush @sites status
```

Or site specific

```
$ drush [site-name] status
```

*Note : You should be in Drupal installation directory to run drush commands.*